# How to embed a local (desktop computer) mp4 into a local XHTML?

Tags: xhtml, mp4

I have an mp4-video on my computer (a Mac). When I drag the file to a browser window in Firefox, the video plays. So obviously all necessary plugins are installed.

But when I try to embed the video into a XHTML file with the `<object>`, `<video>` and/or `<embed>` tags, using code from this site and elsewhere on the web, I see a message that no video was found in a supported format or MIME-type.

**How can I embed a local video into a local XHTML file, so it shows up inside an XHTML page with text surrounding it?**

---

Current code sample:

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls="controls">
    <source src="/path/to/Video%20File.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

does the following work for you?

```
<video width="480" height="320" controls="controls">
  <source src="http://serverIP_or_domain/location_of_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: No. See my code sample in my question. (I'm not pulling the file over http, but from the local file system.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what works is:

```
<embed src="/path/to/Video%20File.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```